# Farm Restore never completing?

Tags: 2007, administration, restore

I started restoring in new environment with central admin GUI. Now It is still showing me "Completing Restore" at SharePoint Search Index place. I was waiting since 4 hours. I checked Restore log file. The last log was written 4 hours back like below

`[12/23/2011 9:57:38 AM]: Progress: [Shared Search Index] 90 percent complete.`

and GUI status is

[image]

What to do? Do I need to interrupt restore process? Or wait for some more time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the event logs to see if there is any activity logged (ULS, Windows Event Logs).

Is the restore using many resources? Check mem, CPU and Disk I/O to see if it is.

From a restoration perspective, if search fails and everything else restores OK, you can rebuild the search index and crawl again after the farm is restored.

Also confirm you are restoring to the same version SQL Server and SharePoint (with the same updates).